# Smooth transitioning from one content image to another

Tags: html, css, transition

```css
.tidings {
    width: 30%;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 3%;
  }

  .tidingsimg:before{
      content: url("https://s4.postimg.org/466igrsgt/Tidingsrune.png");
      position: relative;
      transition: opacity 1s ease;
      -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease;
  }
  .tidingsimg:after{
      content: url("https://s12.postimg.org/83p4b0ubx/Tidingsrune2.png");
      position:absolute;
      top: 0;margin-top: 10px;
      opacity:0;

      transition: opacity 1s ease;
      -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease;
  }
  .tidingsimg:hover:after{
      opacity:1;
  }
  .tidingsimg:hover:before{
      opacity:0;
  }
```

```html
<div class="tidings"><a href="http://hvalla.deviantart.com" class="tidingsimg"></a></div>
```

I have an image that I am trying to have smoothly transition into another image using `content: url`. It works in changing the images abruptly, however I cannot figure out how to apply the transition to actually make it smoothly transition from one image to another. Is it possible to do this using content?

[Here is a JSFiddle showing what I have going on.](https://jsfiddle.net/murf814d/)

Comment: do you want on hover?

Comment: Yes, that's correct - the image should smoothly transition to the other on hover. Sorry, should have specified!

Comment: Is this what you want? https://jsfiddle.net/yxusgu7L/

Comment: Perfect, yes! The :before and :after aspect of it is what was confusing me I think - you helped me out a lot, thanks!

Comment: No problem, happy to help!

Comment: One last question for you - if I wanted the images to resize with my browser window, where would I insert that code? Beforehand, my image links were responsive.

Answer (score 0):

You Should use Before after and set opacity and transition on them

In .tidingsimg:after class we add position:absolute and top: 0;margin-top: 10px; Because without it after style will go far below before style

```css
.tidings {
    width: 30%;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 3%;
  }

  .tidingsimg:before{
      content: url("https://s4.postimg.org/466igrsgt/Tidingsrune.png");
      position: relative;
      transition: opacity 1s ease;
      -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease;
  }
  .tidingsimg:after{
      content: url("https://s12.postimg.org/83p4b0ubx/Tidingsrune2.png");
      position:absolute;
      top: 0;margin-top: 10px;
      opacity:0;

      transition: opacity 1s ease;
      -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease;
  }
  .tidingsimg:hover:after{
      opacity:1;
  }
  .tidingsimg:hover:before{
      opacity:0;
  }
```

```html
<div class="tidings"><a href="http://hvalla.deviantart.com" class="tidingsimg"></a></div>
```